# How to redirect the standard output of dotnet-counter tool by System.Diagnostics.Process?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to redirect the output of dotnet-counter to display to the web application, however, an invalid exception is thrown, here is my code:

```
var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo( "dotnet-counters" )
{
     Arguments = $"monitor --process-id 1",
     CreateNoWindow = true,
     UseShellExecute = false,
     RedirectStandardOutput = true,
     RedirectStandardError = true,
     RedirectStandardInput = true,
};
var process = new Process { StartInfo = startinfo };
process.OutputDataReceived += OnReceived;
process.ErrorDataReceived += OnReceived;
process.Exited += OnExist;

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

When the process started, an error message is read from standard output:

> Unhandled exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot see if a key has been pressed when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.In.Peek

It seems that standard output unable to redirect in this way, any ideas?

Comment: you are asking about redirecting *output*; but the error is about *input*. Does it work if you remove `ReadLine()` functions?

Comment: @Felix if the BeginOutputReadLine and BeginErrorReadLine is remove,the output is no longer available

Comment: wait - your variable is `process`, but you are calling the functions on the class `Process`. don't you get compile error? (I do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative to redirecting output from the tool. The `dotnet-counters` tool uses the `EventCounter` class under the hoods ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventcounter?view=net-5.0)). The values are emitted by the `System.Runtime`event provider amongst [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-counters#dotnet-counters-list).

The nice thing is that those counters can be read [out-of-process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/event-counters#consume-eventcounters), like the tool does. That means you can write your own code to listen to those counters and display them an a webpage with some code like this:

```cs
    var processId = xxxx;
    var providers = new List<EventPipeProvider>()
    {
        new EventPipeProvider("System.Runtime",
            EventLevel.Informational, arguments: new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"EventCounterIntervalSec", "1"}
        })
    };

    var client = new DiagnosticsClient(processId);
    using (var session = client.StartEventPipeSession(providers, false))
    {
        var source = new EventPipeEventSource(session.EventStream);

        source.Dynamic.All += obj =>
        {
            if (obj.EventName == "EventCounters")
            {
                var payload = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj.PayloadValue(0);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", payload.Select(p => $"{p.Key}: {p.Value}")));
            }
        };

        source.Process();
    }
```

The code above shows the raw output:

> Payload: { Name:"cpu-usage", DisplayName:"CPU Usage", Mean:0, StandardDeviation:0, Count:1, Min:0, Max:0, IntervalSec:1.0001626, Series:"Interval=1000", CounterType:"Mean", Metadata:"", DisplayUnits:"%" }
> Payload: { Name:"working-set", DisplayName:"Working Set", Mean:54, StandardDeviation:0, Count:1, Min:54, Max:54, IntervalSec:1.0001626, Series:"Interval=1000", CounterType:"Mean", Metadata:"", DisplayUnits:"MB" }
> Payload: { Name:"gc-heap-size", DisplayName:"GC Heap Size", Mean:1, StandardDeviation:0, Count:1, Min:1, Max:1, IntervalSec:1.0001626, Series:"Interval=1000", CounterType:"Mean", Metadata:"", DisplayUnits:"MB" }
> Payload: { Name:"gen-0-gc-count", DisplayName:"Gen 0 GC Count", DisplayRateTimeScale:"00:01:00", Increment:1, IntervalSec:1.0001626, Metadata:"", Series:"Interval=1000", CounterType:"Sum", DisplayUnits:"" }
> Payload: { Name:"gen-1-gc-count", DisplayName:"Gen 1 GC Count", DisplayRateTimeScale:"00:01:00", Increment:0, IntervalSec:1.0001626, Metadata:"", Series:"Interval=1000", CounterType:"Sum", DisplayUnits:"" }
> Payload: { Name:"gen-2-gc-count", DisplayName:"Gen 2 GC Count", DisplayRateTimeScale:"00:01:00", Increment:0, IntervalSec:1.0001626, Metadata:"", Series:"Interval=1000", CounterType:"Sum", DisplayUnits:"" }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your code, it's in the program that you're attempting to launch. Apparently it uses [Console.ReadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-5.0#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_), which is not allowed when standard input is redirected.

From the documentation:

> **Exceptions**

> *InvalidOperationException*

> The In property is redirected from some stream other than the console.

The only way to avoid this error is to avoid redirecting the input. So change this

```
RedirectStandardInput = true
```

to this

```
RedirectStandardInput = false
```

Comment: same result,you could have a try